# motion tracking by accelerometer inertial sensor

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer, tracking, motion-detection, kinematics

I'm trying to make the hand tracking by an acceloremeter. I don't know if it is a good idea, or is better the optical tracking system. In particular there is an accelerometer mounted on the back of the hand and I want to get the position of the hand in the 3D space. I want to show the hand motion in unity3d.
Now I am using kinematic equations:

```
x = x + vx*t + 1/2*ax*t*t
y = y + vy*t + 1/2*ay*t*t
z = z + vz*t + 1/2*az*t*t
```

where (x,y,z) are the position coordinates, (vx,vy,vz) are the velocity components and ax, ay and az are the acceleration components read from accelerometer and multiplied by 9.81 constant to convert it in m/s/s.

But I haven't good results with this approach. Can someone suggest me a method to track the motion of the hand by means accelerometer?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all accelerometer measures linear acceleration + gravity + noise, so you have to remove gravity and than remove noise from accelerometer readings. Otherwise double integration cause huge errors